# Connect an independent Ionic2+Angular2 based app with a Meteor server via DDP client library

Tags: angular, meteor, ionic-framework, ionic2, ddp

I have an independent Ionic2+Angular2 based mobile application. Also I have an existing Meteor server running on the other hand. I want to use the services of that Meteor Server in my Ionic2+Angular2 application. Is there any way to create a connection via some Meteor DDP client library??

Answer (score 0):

This works well: https://github.com/thomasgazzoni/rxjs-ddp-client

We generally crate a global service with a custom DDP Implementation, subscribes to publications easily.

You just connect to your Meteor Server via the websocket url, default is generally

ws://127.0.0.1:3000/websocket/